# 301 permanent redirect - all get variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have hundreds of pages with different categories.  Is it possible to write one RewriteRule for all?  I want the 301 redirects to go to one page.

**Example pages:**

```
forms-category.html?category=trusts
forms-category.html?category=loans
etc..
```

**All to redirect permanently to one page:**

```
RewriteRule ^forms-category.html?(?:.*)$    final.html  [L,NS,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=[^&]+
RewriteRule ^forms-category\.html$ /final.html? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Technically, the RewriteCond is unnecessary. You should only need this line: `RewriteRule ^forms-category\.html$ final.html? [L,NC,R=301]`

Comment: That's not correct. Rewrite condition is to make sure that only `?category=trusts` OR `?category=loans` is matched in query string.

Comment: Those pages are example pages, but the question itself states that there are hundreds of pages to be redirected. Most likely he doesn't want to have to list each page specifically.